# FirebaseAuth, JWT from provider does not contain a email address before called updateEmailUpdate

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I want to include an email address in JWT from provider(Facebook) when I called `getIDToken()`

when I called `getIDToken()` after `Auth.auth()signInAndRetrieveData()`

the JWT has not an email address information when decode it

but there is an email address when I call `getIDToken()`after `updateEmail()`

```
func firebaseGetIDToken(completion: @escaping (_ idToken: String?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
        let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
        currentUser?.updateEmail(to: "abcd@naver.com") { (error) in
            print("update email \(String(describing:error?.localizedDescription))")
        } <<-- there is no an email address without this code
        currentUser?.getIDToken{ idToken, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Handle error
                print("firebaseGetIDToken error ::: \(String(error.localizedDescription))")
                completion(nil, error)
                return;
            }
            completion(idToken, nil)
        }

    }
```

how could I include an email address into the JWT when I called `getIDToken()` ???

Comment: Are you using the "multiple accounts per email" setting (configured in Firebase Console)?

Comment: I just checked the setting but, no I didn't

Comment: Did you check then whether the Facebook user signing in has an email address or allows their email to be shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sign in via Facebook, you get a [providerData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information) object attached to your user object. In this provider data object you'll find the email for the user. The reason you don't see it in the JWT when you retrieve it is because there is no email attached to the **Firebase** user. When you then call updateEmail() it will update the Firebase user with that email and it will then be in the JWT

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Yes I can found the email address when I signin Facebook and there was an email on identification column on Firebase user console. But it wasn't in JWT, So I updated the email through `updateEmail()` after that the JWT has an email address

Comment: What you are describing there is the wayt the system is intended to work

Comment: So the system does not includes an email address in JWT from Facebook? At the first?

Comment: That is my understanding yes.